# dark theme colors all of a sudden stopped working in atom

Tags: graphics, themes, gpu, atom

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Everything was fine, then all of a sudden atom stops painting the screen properly (like so: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13099). I tried reinstalling but the same issue persists. It only seems to be true for dark themes.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences > Color Profile > Use sRGB color profile